# How to preview icons in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, .ico

Is the preview of an .ico image file in VS Code possible? Any extension needed/available?

All I see are question marks:

[image]

I tried to find an extension that might enable the preview of the .ico image.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code's builtin media preview extension [supports .ico files](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/media-preview#supported-image-file-extensions). If it's not working, either

- something is wrong with your file (it's malformed, in which case I'd suggest trying to open it with other applications that support .ico files),
- or for some reason the "Image Preview" [custom editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors) is not being used by default and some other editor is being used, in which case you can reopen the file with the "Image Preview" editor using the `View: Reopen Editor With...` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette).
- or it's a bug, in which case I'd suggest to raise an issue ticket using `Help > Report Issue` in the menu bar.

**If** you try all that and get nowhere, then maybe try and extension. Ex. [`kisstkondoros.vscode-gutter-preview`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kisstkondoros.vscode-gutter-preview) <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>, which renders image for *URLs* in an editor in the gutter, and when hovering over the URL (really not a great workaround, but technically viable), and [apparently supports .ico files](https://github.com/kisstkondoros/gutter-preview/issues/45).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.